# How to use an instance of a class in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC, i created an object of a class in a controller. Can i use the properties of the object in a view?

```
public ActionResult UploadNew(HttpPostedFileBase fnma1003File)
{
    Loan loan = null;
    if (fnma1003File.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        User currentUser = (User)base.User;
         -------------

     }
 }
```

How to use that currentUser object in my view?

Comment: Either pass it as a model (`return View(currentUser);` or put it in some persistence method like `ViewBag`, `Session`, `TempData`, etc.

Comment: I tried ViewBag.user = currentUser and i couldn't get that .. @JeroenVannevel

Comment: Edit your post with the relevant code and a clear problem description.

Comment: Well I need to clarify one thing User class is not a model class, it is one of the class in the class library

Answer (score 1):

Well one way would be to send it to the view:

```
return View(currentUser);
```

and then reference its type in the View as the Model:

```
@model Full.Namespace.User
```

and then later one use it:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.SomeProperty);
```

---

Another way, though I don't recommend it, would be to pass it in the `ViewBag`:

```
this.ViewBag.User = currentUser;
```

and then in the view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => ((User)ViewBag.User).SomeProperty);
```

Comment: Well i have other stuff to return. I just want to check a property with in that object(whether it is true or not) in the view @neoistheone

Comment: @user2619542, then leverage the `ViewBag` like I showed in the second example. As I stated, it's a way, and so you can definitely do it. Honestly it's made for situations like this.

Comment: @neoistheone I believe that this would be the moment to introduce the concept of **viewmodel**. That is, an object that gives the view everything it needs, without reflecting one single object in the business model. Anyway, your answer is correct, so I'm upvoting it.

Comment: @neoistheone Can i use ViewBag.user in a if condition? because i have to check a property of that object

Comment: @AndreCalil, flattening to a view model is an option. And if it's not a ton of work, then adding that *one property* that's needed off the `User` object is a good candidate.

Comment: @user2619542, of course. You can use it in any valid Razor syntax expression - of which an `if` statement is one.

Comment: @if (Model.submodel.check == false) or if (Viewbag.check == false)

Comment: @neoistheone I understand your point. KISS, right? Anyway, let's look at OP comment: *other stuff to return*. Looks like it's asking for a viewmodel, IMHO.

Comment: @AndreCalil, yes if there is even more information to return that's not part of the domain model that's already setup as the view model then it's time to flatten likely. It's a real subjective discussion.

Comment: Well I need to clarify one thing User class is not a model class, it is one of the class in the class library

Comment: @RyanSchlueter  What does the statement Viebag.check == false means?

Comment: @user2619542, let's clear up the nomenclature. A `ViewModel` is the object that is created to provide all data the `View` needs to work. However, there are times that people end up using the `DomainModel` for the `View` because it has all the data. Then later on they realize they need another data element from somewhere. Often times that means it's time to build a `ViewModel` that looks like the `DomainModel` + other classes. However, sometimes you just need to send that *value or two* in the `ViewBag`. The design decision is yours.

Answer (score 0):

@user2619543 you can set in your c# code viewbag.check or whatever variable name you wanted and then in the view page use.

```
  @(Viewbag.check == false)
{
code to display if false
}
```